# I want to add graphics to this calculator

Tags: java, swing

I want to add graphics to this  calculator with swing but I cannot get past the error display at super.paint(g); Can someone please tell me how to add graphics to this calculator with Swing by getting around this problem. The graphics are already prepared. It says the error is that it cannot resolve:paint(java.awt.Grpahics)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Calculator_ui implements ActionListener
{
   JFrame frame=new JFrame("Calculator");
   JPanel panel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

   JTextArea text=new JTextArea(5,20);

   JButton but1=new JButton("1");
   JButton but2=new JButton("2");
   JButton but3=new JButton("3");
   JButton but4=new JButton("4");
   JButton but5=new JButton("5");
   JButton but6=new JButton("6");
   JButton but7=new JButton("7");
   JButton but8=new JButton("8");
   JButton but9=new JButton("9");
   JButton but0=new JButton("0");

   JButton butadd=new JButton("+");
   JButton butsub=new JButton("-");
   JButton butmulti=new JButton("*");
   JButton butdiv=new JButton("/");
   JButton buteq=new JButton("=");

   JButton butclear=new JButton("C");

   Double number1,number2,result;
   int addc=0,subc=0,multic=0,divc=0;

   public void ui()
   {
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(250,200);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.add(panel);
      panel.add(text);

      panel.add(but1);
      panel.add(but2);
      panel.add(but3);
      panel.add(but4);
      panel.add(but5);
      panel.add(but6);
      panel.add(but7);
      panel.add(but8);
      panel.add(but9);
      panel.add(but0);

      panel.add(butadd);
      panel.add(butsub);
      panel.add(butmulti);
      panel.add(butdiv);
      panel.add(buteq);
      panel.add(butclear);

      but1.addActionListener(this);
      but2.addActionListener(this);
      but3.addActionListener(this);
      but4.addActionListener(this);
      but5.addActionListener(this);
      but6.addActionListener(this);
      but7.addActionListener(this);
      but8.addActionListener(this);
      but9.addActionListener(this);
      but0.addActionListener(this);
      butadd.addActionListener(this);
      butsub.addActionListener(this);
      butmulti.addActionListener(this);
      butdiv.addActionListener(this);
      buteq.addActionListener(this);
      butclear.addActionListener(this);

   }
   public void paint (Graphics g)
   {

      super.paint(g);//Error sign displayed here

      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.fillOval(500,900,20,20);
      g.fillOval(450,850,20,20);
      g.fillOval(500,800,20,20);
      g.fillOval(550,850,20,20);


   }


   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      Object source=e.getSource();

      if(source==butclear)
      {
         number1=0.0;
         number2=0.0;
         text.setText("");
      }
      if(source==but1)
      {
         text.append("1");
      }
      if(source==but2)
      {
         text.append("2");
      }
      if(source==but3)
      {
         text.append("3");
      }
      if(source==but4)
      {
         text.append("4");
      }
      if(source==but5)
      {
         text.append("5");
      }
      if(source==but6)
      {
         text.append("6");
      }
      if(source==but7)
      {
         text.append("7");
      }
      if(source==but8)
      {
         text.append("8");
      }
      if(source==but9)
      {
         text.append("9");
      }
      if(source==but0)
      {
         text.append("0");
      }
      if(source==butadd)
      {
         number1=number_reader();
         text.setText("");
         addc=1;
         subc=0;
         multic=0;
         divc=0;
      }
      if(source==butsub)
      {
         number1=number_reader();
         text.setText("");
         addc=0;
         subc=1;
         multic=0;
         divc=0;
      }
      if(source==butmulti)
      {
         number1=number_reader();
         text.setText("");
         addc=0;
         subc=0;
         multic=1;
         divc=0;
      }
      if(source==butdiv)
      {
         number1=number_reader();
         text.setText("");
         addc=0;
         subc=0;
         multic=0;
         divc=1;
      }
      if(source==buteq)
      {
         number2=number_reader();
         if(addc>0)
         {
            result=number1+number2;
            text.setText(Double.toString(result));
         }
         if(subc>0)
         {
            result=number1-number2;
            text.setText(Double.toString(result));
         }
         if(multic>0)
         {
            result=number1*number2;
            text.setText(Double.toString(result));
         }
         if(divc>0)
         {
            result=number1/number2;
            text.setText(Double.toString(result));
         }
      }
   }

   public double number_reader()
   {
      Double num1;
      String s;
      s=text.getText();
      num1=Double.valueOf(s);

      return num1;
   }




   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Calculator_ui n=new Calculator_ui();
      n.ui();


   }//main
}//class
```

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: `//call the paint method of the superclass JFrame` Your class doesn't extend from `JFrame` actually. In addition: 1) It is not recommended to do custom painting in top-level containers. Use a `JPanel` instead. 2) You should not override `paint()` method but `paintComponent()` instead. See [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Comment: That's why we should **always** use the `@Override` annotation ! @dic19 This could be an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It is not clearly stated what the problem is but looking at your code:

```
public class Calculator_ui implements ActionListener
{
...
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        //call the paint method of the superclass JFrame
        super.paint(g);
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Your class doesn't extend from `JFrame` actually and never is called by the painting mechanism. That's why we should always use `@Override` annotation: if you did you would have a compiling error stating this fact. In fact you should probably have a compiling error saying something like "cannot find symbol: method paint()" at `super.paint(g)` line because, again, your class doesn't extend from `JFrame` or any other [Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29), where this method is defined.

In addition:

1. It is not recommended to do custom painting in top-level containers. Use a `JPanel` instead.
2. You should not override `paint()` method but `paintComponent()` instead. See [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)